# Array ranges for columns in python pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a three column dataset formatted as in the following

```
    t_stamp,Xval,Ytval
    0.000543,0,10
    0.000575,0,10
    0.041324,1,10
    0.041331,2,10
    0.041336,3,10
    0.04134,4,10
    0.041345,5,10
    0.04135,6,10
    0.041354,7,10


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

I wanted to run only for the first 3 rows, I can do it like the following

```
for i in range(1,4):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)
X = df[['X', 'X_t1', 'X_t2', 'X_t3']].values
```

and if I want to do it for 5 ranges, I can do it like the following

```
for i in range(1,6):
        df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)
    X = df[['X', 'X_t1', 'X_t2', 'X_t3', 'X_t4', 'X_t5']].values
```

However, this is not efficient if we want to run it for higher ranges. How can I automate so that we don't have to manually assign the values of X as `X = df[['X', 'X_t1', 'X_t2', 'X_t3']].values` let's say if we want to run for 1000 ranges? Doing `X = df[['X', 'X_t1', 'X_t2', 'X_t3', 'X_t4', ..., 'X_1000']].values` is not efficient.

Comment: A few questions: why do you need the shifted data in memory? Why can't you do it on the fly? Why do you think this is very inefficient? This seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel, I don't think that's a good duplicate, the questions are entirely different. The question, although unclear IMO, shows they know how to access column slices.

Comment: @Mahsolid, I doubt anything besides a communication error happened. StackOverflow prevents all but very experienced users (including preventing myself) from closing answers without consensus for that reason.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh ok, thank you for clarifying this.  Clearly I don't know enough about `pandas`; I'll refrain from flagging `pandas` posts in the future until I am more personally familiar with the technology.  @Mahsolid sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh is correct, SO uses a consensus setup for this very reason. It is not an abuse to flag a post, it helps the OP find the solution to their problem. In this case I was wrong, and so the consensus was not to close the question. Your rep should not be damaged by any of this, nor was anyone else's. And I will be more careful flagging `pandas` posts in the future. I'm not typically wrong when I flag posts, and flagging is typically part of good SO citizenry, so please don't feel attacked or wronged by it.

Comment: @Mahsolid Can you please help me understand why you unmarked my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dict comprehension, build a dict of columns, create a temporary data frame and extract its values:

```
In [1679]: pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['Xval'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).values
Out[1679]: 
array([[  0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan],
       [  3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.],
       [  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.],
       [  5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.],
       [  6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.],
       [  7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.]])
```

Similarly,

```
In [1680]: pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['Xval'].shift(i) for i in range(10)}).values
Out[1680]: 
array([[  0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  nan]])
```

`range` starts from `0`, because `df.shift(0)` is just `X`, which you want as well.

If you want to replace those `nan` values, you can use `df.fillna(0)` first, and *then* extract its values:

```
pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['Xval'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).fillna(0).values
```

Alternatively, apply `np.nan_to_num`:

```
pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['Xval'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values
```

Alternatively, use `dropna`, if you are okay with your dataframe being truncated:

```
In [1763]: pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['Xval'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).dropna().values
Out[1763]: 
array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  5.,  4.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 7.,  6.,  5.,  4.,  3.]])
```

Compare this to the first example, all rows with `nan` are lopped off.